# CountA on a closed workbook not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a Counta function to retrieve the number of columns in a table in a **closed** workbook. That table was created from another table in the same workbook and has hyperlinks in it. The function returns a zero even though there are 4 columns/headers. I need that number to ReDim an array but I get 'Run-time error '9'. When I open the workbook and delete all columns from the right of the table right and all rows from the bottom of the table down, save and close and then try it again, it works. Has anybody experienced this? Thanks for the help!

Here is the formula:

```
=COUNTA('" & FilePath & "[" & fileName & "]" & sheetName & "'!1:1)
```

Comment: Can you paste the formula in your original post?

Comment: What are your variables? In the end it needs to look like `=COUNTA('C:\Users\Me\[myFile.xlsx]MySheet'!1:1)`.

Comment: @BruceWayne - Here is what it looks like: `=COUNTA('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Folder\[File.xlsx]Sheet1'!1:1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helped solve my problem. Apparently, it had something to do with the tables and the calculation setting. Thanks for everyone's input!

```
wbCalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationSemiautomatic

'code here

If wbCalcState <> 0 Then
    Application.Calculation = wbCalcState
Else
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your formula looks right. You may need to use the following code to update external Links.

```
ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
```

Comment: I tried that line but it didn't work. I'm not sure that's what is happening because the links are copied from a worksheet in the same workbook. I can't see any logical reason for the error.